# How to run a command once a ZFS scrub *completes*?

Tags: linux, monitoring, zfs

I would like to use cron to schedule periodic scrubs of my ZFS pool, and at some reasonably short time *after the scrub finishes*, email a status report to myself. The purpose of this is to catch any problems without having to manually look for them (push rather than pull).

The first part is easy: just set up a cron job to run `zpool scrub $POOL` as root at whatever interval is reasonable in my particular situation.

The second part, I'm not quite so sure how to do. `zpool scrub` returns immediately and then the scrub is run in the background by the system (which is certainly desirable behavior if the scrub is initiated by an administrator from a terminal). `zpool status` gives me a status report and exits (with exit code 0 while the scrub is running; it hasn't finished yet so I don't know if the exit status changes once it's done, but I doubt it). The only parameter documented for zpool scrub is `-s` for "stop scrubbing".

**The main problem is detecting the change of status from *scrubbing* to *finished scrubbing*.** Given that, the rest should fall into place.

Ideally, I'd want to tell `zpool scrub` to not return until the scrub finishes, but I don't see any way to make it do that. (It would make it almost too easy to simply cron `zpool scrub --wait-until-done $POOL; zpool status $POOL`.)

Failing that, I'd like to ask the system whether a scrub is currently in progress, preferably in a way that doesn't too much risk breaking with an upgrade or configuration change, so that I can act on whether or not a previously running scrub has finished (by executing a zpool status when the scrub status goes from scrubbing to not scrubbing).

This particular setup is for a workstation system, so while a monitoring tool such as Nagios *probably* has add-ins that would solve the problem, it feels rather overkill to install such a tool for just this one task. *Can someone suggest a lower-tech solution to the problem?*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On [ZFS On Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/), starting with *version 0.6.3* this can be handled quite elegantly by using the **ZFS Event Daemon (zed).** The event daemon, by virtue of monitoring the kernel events directly, can react almost immediately to any events that take place and does not depend on continuous polling and parsing of some other command's output.

Create a shell script with any file name that begins with `/etc/zfs/zed.d/scrub.finish` (for example, `scrub.finish-custom.sh`). That script can take any appropriate action, such as sending an email, writing a log entry somewhere, or making the system sing and dance (OK, maybe not that). Examples are provided that can provide a starting point.

If all you want is to receive an email when the scrub completes, the provided `scrub.finish-email.sh` script will do that nicely. Simply edit /etc/zfs/zed.d/zed.rc to indicate to where the email should be sent and whether an email should be sent also if the pool is not experiencing any problems, make sure something named `scrub.finish` followed by anything in /etc/zfs/zed.d leads to it, and make sure zed is started on boot.

Comment: for the current implementation see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS#Monitoring_/_Mailing_on_Events

Answer (score 5):

Although this question is specific to linux, it is the first google result when searching for *"wait until scrub is finished"*, therefore I'd like to add some useful information for people running OpenSolaris (tested it on OmniOS, but SmartOS, illumos etc. should be similar) instead of Linux (normal Solaris should also work, but I did not test it there).

You can use `syseventadm` to register kernel events. The complete list can be found in `/usr/include/sys/sysevent/eventdefs.h` (just search for "ZFS" in this file). After adding events, the service has to be restarted, for example:

```
syseventadm add -c EC_zfs -s ESC_ZFS_scrub_finish /path/to/script.sh \$pool_name
syseventadm restart
```

This way, the script will be started when any scrubbing of any pool finishes - you have to check inside the script if `$1` equals your desired pool name. Still, it is much less overhead than polling.

Answer (score 4):

I use this simple script for scrubbing status reporting by email.

- [zpadmin](https://github.com/shogsbro/zpadmin)

If you need to detect transition from `scrub running` to `scrub finished` I would check the  `state` field of `zpool status` output. Something like this:

```
# start scrubbing 
zpool scrub ZPOOL

# wait till scrub is finished
while zpool status ZPOOL | grep 'scan:  *scrub in progress' > /dev/null; do
   echo -n '.'
   sleep 10
done

# send a report
zpool status | mail -s "zpool status: ZPOOL" RECIPIENT
```

Comment: I looked at the code, but it seems it only gives you the status when the script is run. How would it notify me when the status goes from "scrubbing" to "finished"?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling the script will not finish as long as the scrub is in progress due to the `while ... done` loop checking for this very condition.

Comment: I think something like this is the way I'll go. By the way, `grep -q` should work as well in that shell script snippet of yours, negating the need to redirect to /dev/null. :)

Comment: Yep, I tested it on Solaris 10 with POSIX grep which lacks this option.

Comment: Ah, OK. GNU grep does have -q with the desired semantics, though.

Comment: This is still a good answer IMO, but with `zed` now in ZFS On Linux, there is an even better way.

Answer (score 2):

I have had much success with [zfswatcher](http://zfswatcher.damicon.fi/)

Answer (score 1):

Recent ZFS versions precisely added what the OP asked: use `-w` to wait for scrub to finish before returning. For example:

`zpool scrub tank -w ; zpool status tank | mail -s "report" me@example.com`